# Unable to connect to Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging, attach-to-process

I want to attach to procces from visual studio 2010 to windows server 2003 on virtual machine, name and password are the same.
On the virtual machine I have Remote Debugging Monitor version 10.0.30319.1
When I try to attach to the process it gives me an error:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps if you could translate some of the Russian (or whatever language that is) it might be easier to assist you.

Comment: @NateZaugg in Russian language is written something like "The requested name is true, but the data of the requested type was found"

Comment: When you setup remote debugging on the target machine it should say in the titlebar something like "user@machine". Are you putting that exact same information into the debugging machine? Are both of the machines on a domain? Are you logged into the remote machine with the same user/pass as the debugging machine? Are the firewalls turned off on each?

Comment: @NateZaugg all information I set right, maybe problem it was be in firewall, this problem is old, but thanks for your proposals